Optimising Makefiles and gcc
I'm a bit of a noob in Make and wrote a makefile which essentially parses my src folder looking for .c files and creates a .so file out of them. I then parse my user folder, searching for .c files, and make a .so file per .c file.
These .so files in /user are dynamically linked using dlopen in a .c file from /src. The libmain.so is also dynamically linked by a Python script.
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(shell nproc)

USR_DIR = ./user
USRS = $(USR_DIR)/*.c
SRCS = ./src/*.c

.PHONY: all clean

all: libmain.so $(USRS:.c=.so)

libmain.so:
    gcc -I./include -fPIC -shared -o libmain.so $(SRCS)
    @touch $@

$(USR_DIR)/%.so: $(USR_DIR)/%.c libmain.so
    gcc -I./include -shared -o $@ -fPIC $< -L. -lmain -Wl,-rpath,.

clean:
    rm -f main $(USR_DIR)/*.o $(USR_DIR)/*.so libmain.so

The problem is that even with the parallelism optimisation I tried to make at the beginning, this takes quite a while to run, especially if there's a lot of files this needs to be done with. Is there any way I can optimise the compilation process?

Why did you include the @touch $@ command?

You should include warning options like -Werror -Wall -Wextra in your compilation commands via a macro and should be using many macros.  However, this is tangential to your main problem.

If you run make twice, does the second run do any compiling?

Note that libmain.so is not rebuilt if any of the files in the src directory changes.  If it is rebuilt, all the files in the src directory are recompiled.  You could avoid that by building object files and linking the object files into the shared object, and making the shared object depend on the object files.  It uses more disk space but saves (re)compilation time.

Do you see evidence of parallel compilation?

You don't specify which version of GNU Make you're using.  This line:
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(shell nproc)

doesn't enable parallel builds in the current instance of make, in all versions; it only works in the newer versions.
If you want to see if it works consider this simple makefile:
a: one two
one two: ; @echo start $@; sleep 1; echo stop $@

MAKEFLAGS += -j2

If parallelism is enabled you'll see:
start one
start two
end one
end two

If it is not enabled you'll see:
start one
end one
start two
end two

In any event, creating so many shared libraries, out of single source files, is certainly unusual.  Normally a project will have only a few shared libraries containing lots of object files.  If you're seeing build performance issues maybe the solution is to reconsider how you organize your code.  Do you really need all those tiny shared libraries?
